# Java Collada Parser - XML Pull based implementation

Tags: java, xml, parsing, collada

I am looking at a set of parsers generated for Atom, XAL, Kml etc. seemingly using an automated technique with a XML pull based parser. The clue towards the automation is presence of "package.html" in all XML-to-Java mapped classes folders. I would like to produce a similar one for the rather large [Collada 1.4](http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_4.pdf) spec. My first attempt with [Altova](http://www.altova.com/) ran into small problems due the "enum" keyword. I am sure I can fix it in the next run with appropriate renaming. Khronos admit to not designing the 1.4 spec to being automated parser generation friendly.

The actual parsers i.e. XAL parser, Atom parser etc. implement the XMLEventParser interface. I would like to know if anybody has encountered/used this pattern. If so which tool can be used to map the XSD to a class set simply giving access to the data components of the nodes using getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it appears that you want to process XML formats like Atom and represent it in objects with getters/setters.  This can easily be done with JAXB.

For an example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Comment: Yes JAXB is an option. But I am looking at a sample implementation using some fancy XmlEvent based pull parsing. The objects are only allocated if they are called for. Getters typically look like - return (String) this.getField("Scheme") in this class generator. I am trying to track down the class generator that was used here. Given the number of classes in the schema I am hard pressed to believe it was hand hacked.